# pyspark toPandas function throws connection error

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I always used this function toPandas() to convert between pyspark and pandas dataframe, but suddenly it throws me error, does any one knows what is the issue of this?

> Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent
> call last) /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in
> collect(self)
> 532         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
> --> 533             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
> 534         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in **call**(self, *args)    1256         return_value =
> get_return_value(
> -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
> 62         try:
> ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
> 64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
> get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 335                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
> --> 336                 format(target_id, ".", name))
> 337     else:
>
> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o42.collectToPython
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in _get_connection(self)
> 928         try:
> --> 929             connection = self.deque.pop()
> 930         except IndexError:
>
> IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in start(self)    1066         try:
> -> 1067             self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))    1068             self.stream = self.socket.makefile("rb")
>
> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Py4JNetworkError                          Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 df_pdf = df.toPandas()
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
> 2140     2141         # Below is toPandas without Arrow optimization.
> -> 2142         pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)    2143     2144         dtype = {}
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
> 531         """
> 532         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
> --> 533             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
> 534         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
> 535
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/traceback_utils.py in **exit**(self,
> type, value, tb)
> 76         SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth -= 1
> 77         if SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth == 0:
> ---> 78             self._context._jsc.setCallSite(None)
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in **call**(self, *args)    1253             proto.END_COMMAND_PART
> 1254
> -> 1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value = get_return_value(    1257
> answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in send_command(self, command, retry, binary)
> 981          if `binary` is `True`.
> 982         """
> --> 983         connection = self._get_connection()
> 984         try:
> 985             response = connection.send_command(command)
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in _get_connection(self)
> 929             connection = self.deque.pop()
> 930         except IndexError:
> --> 931             connection = self._create_connection()
> 932         return connection
> 933
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in _create_connection(self)
> 935         connection = GatewayConnection(
> 936             self.gateway_parameters, self.gateway_property)
> --> 937         connection.start()
> 938         return connection
> 939
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in start(self)    1077                 "server
> ({0}:{1})".format(self.address, self.port)    1078
> logger.exception(msg)
> -> 1079             raise Py4JNetworkError(msg, e)    1080     1081     def _authenticate_connection(self):
>
> Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the
> Java server (127.0.0.1:43593)

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Have you managed to solve it?